# Madexcept Bugreport location under Windows 7

Tags: delphi, madexcept

I've been using Madexcept for quite some time now and it work fine so far. I just noticed though that when I run my application under Windows 7 and an exception occurs, no bugreport.txt is being created. Usually Madexcept saves the bugreport in the programm directory. Under Windows 7 the software should not have the right to do this, that might be the reason why there is not bugreport being created. But I cannot find out how to change the location for the bugreport.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change the location use:

```
uses madExcept;
// ...
 MESettings.BugReportFile := m_szLogPathName;
```

You can do this in your FormCreate and then any logs will be put where you want. Me, I choose the My Documents location.

Comment: awesome! Finally I know how to change the location